# Perf stop showing Events Enabled/Disabled

Tags: bash, perf

I am running the following script

```
#!/bin/bash

ctl_dir=/tmp/

ctl_fifo=${ctl_dir}perf_ctl.fifo
test -p ${ctl_fifo} && unlink ${ctl_fifo}
mkfifo ${ctl_fifo}
exec {ctl_fd}<>${ctl_fifo}

ctl_ack_fifo=${ctl_dir}perf_ctl_ack.fifo
test -p ${ctl_ack_fifo} && unlink ${ctl_ack_fifo}
mkfifo ${ctl_ack_fifo}
exec {ctl_fd_ack}<>${ctl_ack_fifo}

echo Starting

perf stat -D -1 -o perf_out --control fd:${ctl_fd},${ctl_fd_ack} -- ./zstd -kf ../DataSets/enwik9

exec {ctl_fd_ack}>&-
unlink ${ctl_ack_fifo}

exec {ctl_fd}>&-
unlink ${ctl_fifo}

wait -n ${perf_pid}
exit $?
```

The output is filled with these messages from perf.

```
Events enabled
Events disabled
Events enabled
Events disabled
Events enabled
Events disabled
Events enabled
Events disabled
Events enabled
Events disabled
Events enabled
Events disabled
Events enabled
Events disabled
Events enabled
Events disabled
Events enabled
Events disabled
Events enabled
Events disabled
...
```

The zstd displays a progress bar and is not visible at all because of perf's messages.

```
Read:   643 MiB /   954 MiB ==> 31%
```

Unfortunately, zstd too writes to stderr.
Is there any way to stop the Events enabled/disabled messages from showing up on-screen and allow only the progress bar to be displayed while zstd is running?